# How to set up VirtualBox Guest as Server on Different Subnets?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, linux-networking

First, my server only has two public IP addresses.

```
eth1   188.138.124.244 netmask 255.255.255.192 
eth1:0 85.25.110.198 netmask 255.255.255.192 
default gateway: 188.138.124.193
```

How can I set up VirtualBox so that the Guest can be a server and use the 85.25.110.198?

When I attempt to setup bridged networking, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: OK why the downvote? I've been struggling with this problem going on 6 hours now. I've scoured the Internet.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I'm going to guess it's because this is a site for professional sysadmins and your question is *staggeringly* basic, it's also got little, if anything at all, to do with the server being a VM, that VM running on VB and I have no idea why you've added KVM to your tags either.

Comment: @Chopper3 My question was very precise and few details were needed, in my mind. It was how to set up VirtualBox to use two different subnets. An unknown mitigating circumstance was that the ISP filtered by MAC address, which is why it wouldn't work (thanks, pino42!).

Comment: OK I don't understand. This is a SERVER issue. I'm trying to run a *headless* VirtualBox on a DEDICATED server with PUBLIC IPs on DIFFERENT subnets. This isn't a problem ANY home user would EVER run into. How can it *possibly* be off-topic with regard to servers??

Comment: You know, I still want to know why this question was marked off-topic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your provider does not filter your packets by MAC address, you could try removing `eth1:0` altogether from your host configuration and setting its public IP address only in your guest operating system. If it does filter by MAC address, chances are bridged networking won't cut it; perhaps in that case you'd be better off using NAT networking and setting the necessary port forward rules.

Comment: Any idea why the question was marked off-topic? It's 100% dedicated server-related...